# Code not indenting properly. Is there a solution?

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

It seems that the python code in R reticulate is not indenting automatically. E.g. when I write

```
if x < 0:
  print("negative")
  else:
    print("positive")
```

the third line should move automatically at the same level of if but, it actually does not and I get the message `IndentationError: unexpected indent (<string>, line 1)`

Is this bug or can it be corrected?

Comment: This seems more like an IDE-question, than an R-related question?

Comment: I also added the rstudio tag, but other people have the same problem and it is easier to find a solution if I keep the r tag, too.

Comment: I don"t think reticulate implement python automatic indentation at this time, and this must depend on the Rstudio IDE...Indentation is very important in python. See my solution for correct format of this code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by correcting the indentation of you code, following Python rules :

You need to unindent the else so it's indentation match the if ones. Rstudio don't indent correctly for Python to this day.

```
if x < 0:
  print("negative")
else:
  print("positive")
```